# Tumblr Sidebar Changes Size (What's causing this?)

Tags: html, css, width, tumblr, sidebar

My Tumblr blog has multiple pages, and the sidebar shows up slightly smaller on the home page than on all other pages. I am a novice at actually coding HTML/CSS, but I understand it on a basic level and I cannot figure out why this occurs.

I am using the Telpher theme. There is only one id for the sidebar (#sidebar) and the width is set to 21%. Nothing else (that I can discern) is altering the width of the sidebar, but it slightly increases on every non-home page (actually, all of the elements within the sidebar appear to expand a very small amount). The difference is minimal and not really an issue, I'm simply having an aesthetic objection. I've tested this on multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE 11) and the effect is consistent.

The link is [lucidchaosblog.tumblr.com](http://lucidchaosblog.tumblr.com) if you want to see for yourself. I have added a little custom CSS, but I am 100% certain that this issue exists with raw theme as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should ask the maker of the theme.

Comment: As mentioned, it would really help to see the code related to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar seems to be working fine for me in Chrome.

You might need to check your code for these blocks.

```
 {block:PermalinkPage}
 {/block:PermalinkPage}
```

And

```
 {block:IndexPage}
 {/block:IndexPage}
```

It is difficult to tell without seeing the actual theme code (not just the html and css), but these blocks can be used to render different content on different pages. However as I said I think the sidebar looks the same on all pages, so I would expect there to be one block of css and it not change.

You might have to do some swatting up here:
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes

Comment: Let me clarify that the sidebar is expanding by what seems like a few pixels. Also, there is an error in my original post. The sidebar does not expand on every non-index page, but rather on the pages that are re-directed to from my sidebar links. 

I'm seeing this on every browser I have, so it would be that much more strange if you cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I've made a movie here of me clicking through your site, the navigation on the left does not move at all. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IQ2RB2fihDw&feature=youtu.be. When you resize the screen, then the width of the nav is calculated, and elements might get wrapped, but as you said it is 21% wide and this appears to be constant on all pages.